# Перегруженные функции в классе

Tags: c++, функции, классы

я пытаюсь выучить язык С++ но , столкнулся с такой проблемой
Есть класс мне нужно сделать перегруженную функцию

> - −  вычитание векторов (a[i]-b[i] для всех i);

я написал такую функцию

```
const VECTOR& VECTOR::operator-=(const VECTOR& a, const VECTOR&b)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++)
        a.ptr[i] -= b.ptr[i];

    return *this;
}
```

Но функция не работает так слишком много аргументов для функции ,что я делаю не так объясните пожалуйста. Заранее Спасибо

Comment: это же функция класса? тогда Вам нужен один аргумент. и в коде использовать this как второй.

Comment: Оператор `-=` - бинарный, т.е. в нем участвуют 2 (прописью: *два*) операнда.

У вас есть третий операнд - сам объект класса (`*this`). Поэтому вы должны передавать при определении такого оператора только один операнд.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

где то так

```
VECTOR& VECTOR::operator-=(const VECTOR&b)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++)
        ptr[i] -= b.ptr[i];

    return *this;
}
```

Comment: Спасибо большое, разобрался.